# Confuguring Epson Printer in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, epson

I would like to know how to install the drivers for Epson l380 printer in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Answer (score 0):

You can download from the [Epson Download Center](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule). Just type in your model and select Linux as the operating system.